# Connecting Android App running on phone to PC localhost running web service on wifi network

Tags: android, web-services, http

I have the following setup on my wireless network:

[image]

With the webservice running, when I launch the app the HttpClient.execute swallows the execution until it eventually times out and the service is never called (there's a breakpoint set on the product controller). What am I missing here? Nothing's reported in the log.

Comment: Have you put your HttpClient in a separate thread?

Comment: Check your firewall settings on PC. And check your port forwarding - are you forwarding port 80 to 26121?

Comment: Update picture. Pc firewall has a port open on 26121. Android HttpClient is addressing Pc's address and port directly in it's url. Same problem as described above.

Comment: Update - turned off 3g to ensure communication is on my network - same problem. Also, typed 192.168.0.194:26121/api/products/ in the browser - same problem, the connection eventually times out.

Comment: Update - tried running the app in the emulator using the address "http://10.0.2.2:26121/api/products" and this does successfully communicate with the web service. Not sure where the problem lies...